# in safari how to scroll SVG child element into view?

Tags: javascript, svg, safari

Given an SVG that extends beyond the right edge of the window (causing horizontal scrolling) I have the following code that makes the window scroll a given SVG child element into view.

In chrome it is possible to to target an `svg <a>` element. However in firefox I need to select a child element of that `<a>` which is a shape (and not a container like `<a>`).

So far I have not been able to come up with a means to do this in Safari. Is there a solution for this?

```js
//works in chrome
document.getElementById('scroll-this-into-view').scrollIntoView()

//works in firefox and chrome
document.querySelector('#scroll-this-into-view circle').scrollIntoView()

//works in safari 
// ?????????
```

```css
svg {
  width: 4000px
}
```

```html
<svg id="bcfc0609-76dc-45c5-a5bd-e0c1f9faf95a" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 1856 150.03">
    <title>test</title>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="29.5" cy="119.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="179.5" cy="76.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="356.5" cy="60.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="523.5" cy="83.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="706.5" cy="119.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="911.5" cy="83.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="1177.5" cy="90.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a id="scroll-this-into-view" href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="1525.53" cy="29.5" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <circle cx="1826.5" cy="120.53" r="29.5" style="fill: #c13030" />
    </a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short of something cleaner the solution I am using for now is:

```
 const circle = document.querySelector('#scroll-this-into-view circle')
 const circleBoundingRect = circle.getBoundingClientRect()
 window.scrollTo(circleBoundingRect.left - 50 + window.scrollX, 0)
```